# How to violate a foreign key in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

Hi people I have the following relationship:

```
ALTER TABLE Role ADD CONSTRAINT ACTOR_ROLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (actorID) REFERENCES Actor (actorID);
```

What query can I construct to test if this working correctly

Thanks I would like it to be tested from a UPDATE command thanks

please not this is not the same as my previous question as I am asking how to violate a Foreign Key

Thank you for your kind help

Comment: If you want me to display more of my information please let me know before marking this as a poor and negative question as I dont know what it is you require thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO Role (actorID) VALUE(X) 
-- replace X with a number that doesn't exist in the Actor table
```

Comment: @user1137472:  Sure, just update a valid row and set the actorid column to something that doesn't exist in the Actor table.

Comment: Will an update command begin with UPDATE INTO or UPDATE Role set (actorID) VALUE(X)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a row in `Role` whose `actorID` does not exist in table `Actor`.

Comment: I have the following:

UPDATE Actor set lastName = 'Voight', birthDate = '29-Dec-1938' WHERE ActorID = '00069';

and i changed the actor ID to 99 which does not exist it still updated

Comment: Could you give an example of the syntax

Answer (score 2):

```
Update Role
set actorID = '99'
where actorid = '00069'
```

This assumes that the actor table has actorid = '00069' and that it does not have actorid = '99'